# defaultTheme is not defined using Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-slick

I was working on project where I used [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) with [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), and I did some customization in styling, like used **react-slick** for **slider**, and I **applied custom CSS** to react-slick slider classes and made slider as I want to... but meanwhile I am trying to apply default custom fonts to my entire project. In that case, I made some changes in the file of

#### File *tailwind.config.js*

```
theme: {
  fontFamily: {
    customfontname: ['Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.customfontname],
  },
  extend: {},
},
```

**After that, I got a** ***compile error:***

> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css
>
> **ReferenceError: defaultTheme is not defined**

#### My Tailwind CSS *Config.js* file for reference

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./page-section/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./page-section/**/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      customfontname: ['Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.customfontname],
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        customfontname: ['Segoe UI',
                         'Helvetica Neue',
                         'Arial',
                         'sans-serif',
                         ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.customfontname],
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This is the code of people who trying to help me, but I getting the same error as I mentioned...

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./page-section/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./page-section/**/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      customfontname: [
        "Segoe UI",
        "Helvetica Neue",
        "Arial",
        "sans-serif",
        ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.customfontname,
      ],
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: there is this line `const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')` in [tailwind's doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#customizing-the-default-theme). do you have this line in your `tailwind.config.js`?

Comment: @Layhout please check my config file for reference I have added it.

Comment: try put that line at the top in `tailwind.config.js`.

Comment: I put still not working.

Comment: maybe something to do with the tailwind version. i see you have `mode: "jit",`. the latest tailwind version uses `jit` by default.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: i suggest you should apply you custom font inside your `global.css` instead of `tailwind.config.js` since i also did it that way.

Comment: @Jason0011 you need to kill your dev server & re-run it yarn dev to get this to work. Probably to do with the additional import/require (in case you don't see it in the answer). I had the same problem and it worked for me after I did this...

Answer (score 4):

Add your `customfontname` inside `extend` of your theme

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {     //  Add it inside this 
     fontFamily: {
      customfontname: ['Segoe UI', 
                       'Helvetica Neue', 
                       'Arial',
                       'sans-serif',
                       /*...*/ defaultTheme.fontFamily.customfontname],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, still getting same error.

Comment: Have you added the first line ? defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

Comment: yes, i added as its mention.

Comment: You are still getting `defaultTheme` not defined ?? It is strange!

Comment: yes, still same error..

Comment: Hey, I was able to solve the issue by including the import statement just below the `@type` line.

Comment: @Avik can you pls show ur code what u did let me check..

Comment: @Jason0011 I just added the `const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')` after the `/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */` line. And it worked.

Comment: If you have already tried this, it would be great if you could create a new boilerplate using the `nextjs-tailwind` template and transfer your files to that new folder. 
I have faced this kind of situation before! Trust me, that's the best option.

Comment: ( TypeError: defaultTheme.fontFamily.customfontname is not iterable ) I got this error now @Avik and how to create a boilerplate?

Comment: `npx create-next-app --tailwind with-tailwindcss-app`

Comment: @Jason0011 you need to kill your dev server & re-run it `yarn dev` to get this to work. Probably to do with the additional import/require.